# Pascal : write a very long string without reference-counted types (ex:ansistring)

Tags: freepascal

I'm making a unit library in pascal at the moment. I would like to know whether I could assign a very long string without using Ansistring or {$H+}, because I couldn't assign typed files with reference-counted types. Thanks before.
EDIT : Code added

```
type
dataFilm = record
    title : array [1..255] of char;
    genre : array [1..255] of char;
    viewerRating : array [1..255] of char;
    duration : integer;
    synopsis : array [1..2000] of char;
    priceWeekdays : longint;
    priceWeekend : longint;
end;  
theatreUDT = record
    mainDataFilm : array [0..100] of dataFilm;
    end;  
ftheatreUDT = record
    fmainDataFilm : file of dataFilm; //It fails here when i use   ansistring
end;  
procedure loadMain(var main : theatreUDT; var fmain:ftheatreUDT);
begin
    assign(fmain.fmainDataFilm,'Data/dataFilm.dat');
    reset(fmain.fmainDataFilm);
end;
```

The program has no problem at all, only, it can't hold a very long string for synopsis.

Comment: I don't think that SetLength work for me, because when i try to print out the file, it was cut out somewhere.

Comment: I think you might like to avoid using legacy I/O and find that your problems dissolve. It's time to leave the 1980s behind.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sorry, but I don't know much about pascal. I was given an assignment to make .dat I/O in pascal but one of the file has a very long string. I had no clue at all on how to do it without ansistring because typed files couldn't be assigned with reference-counted types like Ansistring.

Comment: You've not given any details here so we can't tell you how to solve your problem either. Do you have to use a file containing fixed length records? Why aren't you using something like JSON?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Pardon me, I will give the code ASAP.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan code added. Pardon me for that. And sorry, but I don't understand most terms you've just added(like JSON). I'm in my first year of college at the moment. Again, I apologize if I don't understand most of your terms.

Comment: Once again I ask you why you are using fixed length records. It's 2016. Your code is very poorly formatted. Please read the help on formatting in the edit window.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it's because that that's the only thing my lecturer taught us. And in our assignment, we are told to use UDT to increase our score. perhaps you have any reading source i could read to improve my code? I'm sorry if my code is poorly formatted.

Comment: So how many characters do you want to reserve for this string? You have to make that decision. You cannot have arbitrary length strings in a fixed length record for reasons that should be obvious. As for code formatting, please fix it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan something like a synopsis-like. around 1000-2000 char.

Comment: If you want a fixed length string, then you have to, well, fix the length. So, pick a length. Then you'll need to declare it as an array of characters. And then probably wrap it with a property getter/setter that allows you to view that array as a string. In the real world you would not use a fixed length.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ah i get it now. Thank you for your help and your patience! It worked. I've edited the code above. That should go well right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array of char` to have longer strings.

```
dataFilm = record
    title : string;
    genre : string;
    viewerRating : string;
    duration : integer;
    synopsis : array[0..1999] of char; 
    priceWeekdays : longint;
    priceWeekend : longint;
end;
```

However, note that this is not a very good solution because

a) it means that you have to choose a maximum length for the string. If you choose the length too small, some texts will not fit. If you choose the length too big, you waste lots of disk space because the space a record in the file takes is always the same based on the definition of the record.

b) you cannot easily modify the structure of the data. For example, if you want to add a "director" field to the information about the movie, you cannot do so without writing code to convert the old file format to the new file format. Basically you cannot change the definition of the dataFilm type once you have created files with this code.

c) You cannot easily look into the files any other way. If you use some standard like JSON or XML or even a database, you can easily look at the content with other tools.

d) you cannot access the files with other programming environments as easily. You might want to migrate from Pascal to some other environment in the future or allow other tools to access the files. This is easier using some standard format or a database than when using the pascal way.